# Change standard behaviour of pasted text?

Tags: scrivener

Word 365 has a useful option, which allows you to change the standard behaviour of pasting text, meaning you can set the pasting mode to "Text Only" by default:
  [image: Word 365 - Keep Text Only]
I have lots of notes on Google Keep, which I usually want to transfer to Scrivener. However, I always have to remove the text formatting manually, either by pasting it into regular notepad first, which gets tiring because you have to copy-paste everything twice everytime, or use the shortcut CTRL-SHIFT-V shortcut, which is too close to CTRL-SHIFT-C, meaning I'll accidently hit that shortcut at some point instead...
I want to know if Scrivener has a similair option, allowing me to have all text formatting automatically removed whenever I paste something into Scrivener.

Comment: Workaround: When you have to perform repetitive operations in a GUI, a keyboard automation application may be just the thing. You may want to take a look at AutoHotKey for Windows or Automator for Mac. These apps will allow you to do things as simple as replacing text similar to an autocorrect function or arbitrarily complex multi-step operations. They make it look like their actions are coming from the keyboard and mouse, so they will work with almost any application without the application even knowing they are there. Each macro is usually bound to a hotkey or trigger phrase. ...

Comment: ... Getting one macro to work with multiple applications can be a bit tricky, but is certainly doable. (I use AutoKey on Linux.) In your case, you could do something as simple as taking some unassigned key code such as Super+P and have it emit a Ctrl+Shift+V - with no chance of typing something else unfortunate. Or, you could just get both apps open with your mouse cursor on the note to transfer and then have a macro do the whole thing.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for that. I hoped I wouldn't have to use another software for this, especially when it comes to pasting text, but if this question remains unanswered for even longer, I guess this will have to do.

Comment: Adding another piece to the puzzle is never ideal, but once you start using one of these tools, you'll wonder how you ever got by without it. You could also look into remapping one or more keys on your keyboard to do what you want. I know a little about doing that in Linux, but not in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a clipboard manager like flycut for mac osx (similar tools exist for other platforms). What these programs do, is save everything you copy to a list. You can configure what hotkey you want to use to paste from such a program, or in the case of flycut, simply select your text from it's list in the notification area when you are ready to paste into scrivener. The nice thing about doing it this way is you are always sure of what you are about to paste, and can paste something you copied in the past if the most recent "copy" wasn't what you want.

It's a little easier than setting up a macro, and will work for any program you want to paste into, not just scrivener.